# Typescript - directories with mixed tsconfig (different module types)

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I have a software with this structure:

/src/vscode/ few ts files.
/src/webview/ few ts files.

Now I want to compile the code to the /out directory, but use "commonjs" as module type for the vscode folder and "esnext" for the webview folder.
is, and how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use different tsconfigs in each of those folders

The root tsconfig should mention them `references`

@see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html

Comment: I tried this, but this did not work.
No error, but also nothing is compiled.